# Excel sheets are being modified by another Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

This is not related to programming but has been puzzling me for a couple of days. I have an Excel workbook with multiple sheets that I use as a tool that calculates the values I've given in input against data from green screens. After comparing them, I will save the input sheet and output sheet in a separate Excel document and continue with other data inputs. But whenever I run the tool, all the Excel sheets that I've saved previously are being modified with the latest results.

I found the problem, which is: "I am creating a new document by clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> from the tool which is creating a link to the tool".

Now my query is, Why is this link being created and able to modify the results of all documents?

Comment: why negative votes for this?

Comment: If your formulae look like `=+[book1.xls]Sheet1!A1+[book.xls]Sheet1!A2` i.e. they contain references to the original workbook, then changing the original data will probably cause all linked workbooks to be updated when opened. Removing the workbook references should help. You can also check for Workbook Connections on the Data tab (at least it can be found there in Excel 2010, I'm not sure about 2007).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest/dirtiest solution might be to Copy each of your input/output pairs of sheets and Paste Special/Values, to convert all formulae therein (including references to other sheet or books) into their resultant values. This cannot be undone later, except with Undo.

More selective, would be to [break the links](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/break-a-link-to-an-external-reference-HP010217691.aspx).

However there is a more flexible option (also under Data/Connections/Edit Links) under Startup Prompt, where you could choose Don't display the alert and don't update automatic links. This should freeze the values as when created, but the chances are that at some point they may be updated, even if by mistake, anyway.